# How to parse the key-value json in oracle 12.1?

Tags: json, oracle, jsonparser, json-path-expression

I have below SQL query in Oracle 12c ( 12.1 and NOT 12.2. So I cannot use JSON_OBJECT_T ) . I need to print first column ( say key_str)  with value like ABC, DEF etc while second column ( say val_str) as 123, 456 etc. However , I am unable to come up with Oracle Json expression to do this. Can someone please point what I need to do ? I tried already many permutations combinations but that did not help.

```
  with json as   
( select '{
    "ABC": "123",
    "DEF": "456",
    "GHI": "789" }' doc   
  from   dual   
)   
select   key_str
, val_str
FROM  json_table( (select doc from json) , '$'   
                COLUMNS ( key_str PATH '$[0]'     
                        , val_str PATH '$[1]'   
                        )   
               )
```

Comment: The input is an object, but your query treats it as an array. Is that on purpose? Then: do you, or do you not, know the key names ahead of time (like "ABC" and "DEF")? If you don't, then it will be more complicated, since in handling JSON, the normal assumption is that you know attribute (key) names ahead of time, not just from inspecting the data.

Comment: Thank you. I have json available from other system in the given format only ( that is 'json object' ) . I do not know key names ahead . That is the reason, I am trying to retrieve data based on index location rather than using keyname.

Comment: OK. Retrieving based on "index location" makes no sense, since in JSON, the order of key-value pairs is irrelevant (two JSON documents are "equal" if the only difference is the order of such pairs). Question: Will the document will always consist of a single object, with an unknown number of key-value pairs, with all the values being scalar? Or can some values, sometimes, be smaller objects, or arrays, etc.?

Comment: The json document will always consist of a single object, with an unknown number of key-value pairs separated by comma.